# Custom data format - `Deserializer::deserialize_str` implementation

Tags: rust, serde

[Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a1aa36098b895b3b24839648721e7502) to playground

I am trying to implement a custom data format with `serde`, I've been struggling with the `deserialize_str` method

```rust
pub struct Deserializer<R> {
    rdr: R,
}

impl<'de, 'a, R: io::Read + 'de> de::Deserializer<'de> for &'a mut Deserializer<R> {
    fn deserialize_str<V>(self, visitor: V) -> Result<V::Value>
    where
        V: Visitor<'de>,
    {
        let len = self.read_i16()?; // implemention below
        if len == 0 || len == -1 {
            return visitor.visit_borrowed_str("");
        }
        let len = len as usize;
        let buf = self.read_exact(len)?; // implemention below
        let out_str = std::str::from_utf8(&buf)?;

        // visitor.visit_borrowed_str(out_str) doesn't compile
        visitor.visit_str(out_str) // compiles but errors
    }
}

impl<R: io::Read> Deserializer<R> {
    fn read_exact(&mut self, len: usize) -> Result<Vec<u8>> {
        let mut buf = vec![0; len];
        self.rdr.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
        Ok(buf)
    }

    fn read_i16(&mut self) -> io::Result<i8> {
        self.rdr.read_i16::<byteorder::NetworkEndian>()
    }
}
```

When using `visitor.visit_borrowed_str(out_str)`, I get the error

```
    |
94  | impl<'de, 'a, R: io::Read + 'de> de::Deserializer<'de> for &'a mut Deserializer<R> {
    |      --- lifetime `'de` defined here
...
149 |         let out_str = std::str::from_utf8(&buf)?;
    |                                           ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
150 |
151 |         visitor.visit_borrowed_str(out_str)
    |         ----------------------------------- argument requires that `buf` is borrowed for `'de`
152 |     }
    |     - `buf` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I understand that `out_str` needs to somehow live longer than its scope, but I can't find a way to go about it.

Comment: Perhaps [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1413) is relevant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `visit_borrowed_str`, you need to hand it a reference to something that lives as long as your deserializer. Creating a new temporary `Vec` with `read_exact` won't do, you need to get access to the underlying slice, e.g. `std::str::from_utf8(self.rdr.get_ref()[self.rdr.position()..][..len])` or similar. If you want to keep `R` a generic `std::io::Read`, I think you can't use `visit_borrowed_str`. `serde_json` e.g. handles this by having a special `Read` that returns a reference to the underlying data [if it can](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.79/src/serde_json/read.rs.html#456-466), and then only uses `visit_borrowed_str` [if it does have a reference](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.79/src/serde_json/de.rs.html#1345-1348) to the underlying data.

Also, if you ask a deserializer to deserialize to a borrowed string when it can't, it must necessarily error. That [holds true](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a5c512f2dbb6dd86085960eaf3114aa1) for `serde_json` as well. So the error from `visit_str` is not an error in your deserializer implementation, but an error in how you use the deserializer. You should have asked to deserialize to a `String` or `Cow<str>` instead (not that your serializer could ever give you a `Cow::Borrowed`, but asking for a `&str` just isn't a good idea with any deserializer, asking for a `Cow<str>` is the thing generally recommended instead).